# How to locate installed software command in Red Hat Linux 5?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, nmap

I just installed nmap. I downloaded it; saved it to my desktop; and just double clicked the rpm package. The installation was successful. Now, when I tried in bash to run `nmap` it did not recognise the command.

I'm from Windows so I don't even know where to locate the "exe" for nmap so that I can run it.

I checked in `/etc` and `/bin` and `/opt` but I did not see any install folder for `nmap`.

**Steps used to install it**

ALL STEPS are performed with `root` from `~` location.

- 1 : Download `i686 (32-bit Linux) Nmap RPM: nmap-7.40-1.i686.rpm` from https://nmap.org/download.html and save the file on the`Desktop` folder.
- 2 : I tried `rpm -i nmap-7.40-1.i686.rpm` but it failed. The error is

  > Failed dependencies:
  >
  > rpmlib(Filedigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by nmap-7.40-1.i686
  >
  > rpmlib(PayLoadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by nmap-7.40-1.i686
- 3 : I therefore decided to double click the file on my desktop. ANd it said "Installation successful"

[image: Image of successfull installation]

Comment: did you perchance download the "src.rpm" file?

Comment: Which `src.rpm` ? I only downloaded `i686 (32-bit Linux) Nmap RPM: nmap-7.40-1.i686.rpm` from https://nmap.org/download.html

Comment: just confirming the steps you took -- installing a src.rpm would *not* (immediately) provide an executable

Comment: did you install it as root, or did it prompt you for credentials to install as root?

Comment: Its in /usr/bin....are you sure you have /usr/bin in your PATH?

Comment: @JeffSchaller please see the update on my OP post

Comment: @mdpc Yup. Please see the update of my OP

Comment: I am suspicious of your GUI installer, given that the "low-level" RPM command complained/failed.

Answer (score 2):

The package for centos 7 at least places `nmap` in `/usr/bin`, though these `rpm` commands should apply to Redhat 5 (or RHEL5, both of which have or are busy falling off the support wagon). Find the `nmap` package, and then `grep` that package's contents for `nmap`:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep nmap
nmap-6.40-7.el7.x86_64
nmap-ncat-6.40-7.el7.x86_64
$ rpm -ql nmap-6.40-7.el7.x86_64 | grep bin/nmap
/usr/bin/nmap
$
```

Comment: It did not find anything. I dont understand I downloaded it from https://nmap.org/download.html  `i686 (32-bit Linux) Nmap RPM: nmap-7.40-1.i686.rpm` It was saved on the desktop and I just double clicked the package and it installed it.

Comment: `rpm -qa` should show all installed packages. I have no idea what double clicking on a `.rpm` file does, maybe try instead `rpm -i nmap-7.40-1.i686.rpm` to install it?

Comment: I tried it but it says : failed dependencies ; rpmlib(Filedigests) and rpmlib(PayLoadIsXz) are needed by nmap-7.40-1.i686.  But when I doubled clicked `nmap-7.40-1.i686.rpm` on my desktop, it installed it successfully

Comment: Given that `rpm -i` failed and that that `rpm -qa` can't find it I strongly suspect that the package is not installed. What makes you think clicking on it installed it successfully?

Comment: please see the update on my OP

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Linux there are no `.exe` files; the `.exe` extension is an artifact of the days of DOS. The most common way to find out where an executable file is that I've seen is to run `which` with the command name, so in this case it would be `which nmap`.

On most Red Hat family systems, the result will be:

```
# which nmap
/usr/bin/nmap
```

Comment: I did `# which nmap` it says no nmap in all folders. But I double clicked the `.rpm` and it launched the GUI installer. It was successfull

Comment: please see the update on my OP